# How can I use BytesIO as a pandas.read_csv data source

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oracle, csv

I am trying to perform a csv data parsing using pandas.read_csv(bytes, chunksize=n) where bytes is a ongoing stream of data which I want to receive from a database CLOB field, reading it by chunks.

```
reader = pandas.read_csv(io.BytesIO(b'1;qwer\n2;asdf\n3;zxcv'), sep=';', chunksize=2)
for row_chunk in reader:
  print(row_chunk)
```

Code above is working fine, but I want to use some updatable stream instead of fixed `io.BytesIO(b'...')`
I tried to redefine read method like this

```
class BlobIO(io.BytesIO):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._chunk_size = 4
        self._file_data_table = 'my_table'
        self._job_id = 'job_id'
        self._get_raw_sql = """
            select dbms_lob.substr(body, {0}, {1})
            from {2}
            where job_id = '{3}'
        """
        dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('host', 'port', 'service_name')
        self.ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect('ora_user', 'ora_pass', dsn_tns)
        self.res = b''
        self.ora_cur = self.ora_con.cursor()
        self.chunker = self.get_chunk()
        next(self.chunker)

    def get_chunk(self):
        returned = 0
        sended = (yield)
        self._chunk_size = sended or self._chunk_size
        while True:
           to_exec = self._get_raw_sql.format(
               self._chunk_size,
               returned + 1,
               self._file_data_table,
               self._job_id)
           self.ora_cur.execute(to_exec)
           self.res = self.ora_cur.fetchall()[0][0]
           returned += self._chunk_size
           yield self.res
           sended = (yield self.res)
           self._chunk_size = sended or self._chunk_size
           if not self.res:
               break

    def read(self, nbytes=None):
        if nbytes:
            self.chunker.send(nbytes)
        else:
            self.chunker.send(self._chunk_size)
        try:
            to_return = next(self.chunker)
        except StopIteration:
            self.ora_con.close()
            to_return = b''
        return to_return

buffer = BlobIO()
reader = pandas.read_csv(buffer, encoding='cp1251', sep=';', chunksize=2)
```

but it looks like I'm doing something completely wrong because `pd.read_csv` never got executed here at the last line and I don't understand what is happening there.

Maybe creating `buffer = BytesIO(b'')` and then writing new data to the buffer `buffer.write(new_chunk_from_db)` could be a better approach but I don't understand when exactly should I call such a write action.

I believe I can create a temporary file with the contents of a CLOB which I can then pass to `read_csv`, but I really want to skip this step and read data directly from database.

Please give me some directions.

Comment: Do you have fixed row length? If not the usage of `substr` for the chunks is problematic, as it will not align with the rows...

Comment: Actually no, the plan was to use this mechanism to parse arbitrary csv data, reading it from clob

Answer (score 0):

cx_Oracle provides native way to read LOBs. Seems like overriding BytesIO read with cx_Oracle LOB read does the job:

```
class BlobIO(BytesIO):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.res = b''
        self.ora_con = db.get_conn()
        self.ora_cur = self.ora_con.cursor()
        self.ora_cur.execute("select lob from table")
        self.res = self.ora_cur.fetchall()[0][0]
        self.offset = 1

    def read(self, size=None):
        r = self.res.read(self.offset, size)
        self.offset += size
        # size + 1 should be here to perform nonoverlaping reads
        # but looks like panadas C parser uses some kind of overlaping
        # because while testing size+1 - parser occasionally missed some bytes
        if not r:
            self.ora_cur.close()
            self.ora_con.close()
        return r

blob_buffer = BlobIO()
reader = pandas.read_csv(
        blob_buffer, 
        chunksize=JobContext.rchunk_size)
for row_chunk in reader:
    print(row_chunk)
```